# Difference between [...]Async and Begin[...] .net asynchronous APIs

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, sockets, asynchronous

Can anybody explain me what is the difference between the Begin[...]/End[...] asynchronous API pattern and the later [...]Async pattern in .NET 3.5?

- Why was the later created?
- Why would one prefer one pattern over another?

For example, Socket.BeginAccept() and Socket.AcceptAsync().

Comment: The currently selected answer is not appropriate. The answer by Stephen is more accurate. Please update this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MSDN will answer that better than me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx

> The main feature of these enhancements
>   is the avoidance of the repeated
>   allocation and synchronization of
>   objects during high-volume
>   asynchronous socket I/O. The Begin/End
>   design pattern currently implemented
>   by the System.Net.Sockets.Socket class
>   requires a System.IAsyncResult object
>   be allocated for each asynchronous
>   socket operation.

Answer (score 19):

Note that most `*Async` methods (with corresponding `*Completed` events) are using the [Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkasytyf.aspx). The older (but still perfectly valid) `Begin*` and `End*` is a pattern called the [Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx). *The `Socket` class is an exception to this rule; its `*Async` methods do not have any corresponding events; it's essentially just APM done in a way to avoid excessive memory allocations.*

The biggest difference between APM and EBAP is the thread used for completion notification. APM will call back on a thread pool thread (unless the request completes synchronously). EBAP will use a cross-framework strategy to call back on a UI thread (if the operation was started from a UI thread).

However, both APM and EBAP are being replaced with a much more flexible approach based on the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Since the TPL can wrap APMs easily, older classes will likely not be updated directly; extension methods are used to provide `Task` equivalents for the old APM methods.

**Update 2012-07-14:** I was wrong when I stated "older classes will likely not be updated directly". For performance reasons, the BCL/TPL teams decided to review each BCL type and add TAP methods directly instead of using extension methods. These changes will be in .NET 4.5.